# How to compute mean and std in special ROI region in 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have a 2D matrix value in left side and ROI of yellow color in right side. I want to compute the mean and standard dirivation only in yellow color by Matlab code. How to implement it? I tried some way but it give wrong result. This is my implementation

[image]

```
I =[ 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     5     4     8     0     0     0     0
     0     0     4     0     0     9     0     0     0
     0     0     6     0     1     9     0     0     0
     0     0     0     2     2     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0]
%% ROI is 1 for region of interesting.
ROI=[0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0]


%% Compute mean and std of ROI region
  mean=mean(I.*ROI)
  std=std(I.*ROI)
```

Comment: **DO NOT** use the same name for the receiving variable and the function you are calling (`mean=mean(I.*ROI)` and `std=std(I.*ROI)` are dangerous). Just try `myVariableWithACoolName = std(I(logical(ROI)));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `ROI` to subset into your data and find the mean and standard deviation of the subset:

```
ROI = ROI == 1;
m = mean(I(ROI));
s = std(I(ROI));
```

This will ensure that you only include the portions of the data you want before calculating the mean and standard deviation of your data.  The first line of code ensures that `ROI` is a `logical` array.  The next two lines compute the mean and standard deviation of the affected area.  Bear in mind that `I(ROI)` will extract out a 1D unravelled version of the ROI data, and you can use this directly into `mean` and `std`.

Running the above code with your example gives me:

```
I =[ 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
0     0     5     4     8     0     0     0     0
0     0     4     0     0     9     0     0     0
0     0     6     0     1     9     0     0     0
0     0     0     2     2     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0];
%% ROI is 1 for region of interesting.
ROI=[0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0];

ROI = ROI == 1;
m = mean(I(ROI));
s = std(I(ROI));
```

---

```
>> m

m =

    3.1250

>> s

s =

    3.3838
```

Comment: Totally rigth! Made a noob mistake in my answer

Comment: @user8430 - Worked for me.  Did you convert `ROI` to a logical array as in the first line of code?  You probably just used the second and third line of code, which is incorrect.

Comment: @user8430 - Added in a numerical example.

Comment: @user8430 - Do `clear mean; clear std;` then try again.  You are shadowing the function names with the variables.

Comment: Right. I did not clean mean variable what I created before. Sorry for that

Comment: @user8430 - Thanks!  Good luck!